# Basic questions about $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, the-baire-space

can someone please let me know if the following is correct:

1) Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the integers endowed with the discrete topology and $\mathbb{N}$ the natural numbers. Is $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ a discrete space with the product topoogy?

2) Does $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ contain a compact infinite set?

3) Is $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ metrizable?

My work:

1) I think this is false, let $A= \{0\} \times \{0\} \times ...$ Suppose $A$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ then we can find a basic open set $U=\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{n}$ such that $(0,0,0,...) \in U \subset A$. By definition of product topology there exists a natural number $J$ such that if $n>J$ then $U_{n} = \mathbb{Z}$. This in turn implies that:

$U_{1} \times U_{2} ...\times U_{J} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} ... \subset  \{0\} \times \{0\} \times ...$

which is not true since we can pick $z \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ then $(0,0,...0,z,z,z...)$ is the LHS while not in the RHS.

2) Can we simply say, take $\{0,1\}$ endowed with the discrete topolgy then $\{0,1\}$  is compact since it is finite. But then by Tychonoff theorem $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact and clearly infinite.

3) I think this one is true right? $\mathbb{Z}$ is metrizable (e.g discrete metric) and the countable product of metrizable spaces is metrizable.

Comment: 1) no, it is homeomorphic to the set of irrational numbers. 2) yes, it contains $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, as you say 3) yes, a countable product of metrizable spaces is metrizable.

Comment: @Theo Buehler: without using the homeomorphism you mention, how would you prove it is not discrete?

Comment: Your argument is fine. Note that $(0,\cdots,0,1,0,\cdots)$ ($1$ at entry $n$) converges to zero as $n \to \infty$ by what you say. Alternatively, prove 3) by writing down an explicit metric and check that this sequence converges to zero.

Comment: @user10: just exhibit a nontrivial convergent sequence.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The space $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is of course homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, is often called the [Baire space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_%28set_theory%29) — not to be confused with spaces satisfying the [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), which are also called [Baire spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space). Using continued fractions one can show that $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is homeomorphic to the subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of the irrational numbers. If you believe this last fact, all your questions become rather obviuous. Here are some comments on your approach:

1. Your argument in 1) shows that the sequence $x_{n} = (0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ (the $1$ appears at the $n$th entry) converges to $0$. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not discrete, and as it is a topological group, it contains no isolated points at all.
2. Yes, you can embed the space $C = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ into $\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}}^{\mathbb{N}}$. As a product of compact spaces, $C$ is compact (alternatively, show that $C$ is homeomorphic to the usual [Cantor ternary set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)). The obvious map $C \to \mathbb{Z^N}$ (coming from the inclusion ${0,1} \to \mathbb{Z}$) is continuous and injective, hence a homeomorphism onto its image, as $C$ is compact and $\mathbb{Z^N}$ is Hausdorff. Clearly $C$ is uncountable.
3. It is not hard to check that a countable product $X = \prod X_i$ of metric spaces is metrizable, for instance $\sum 2^{-i} \frac{d_i}{1+d_i}$ furnishes a compatible metric. If each $X_n$ is separable/completely metrizable then so is $X$.

As a last remark, the Baire space is a separable, completely metrizable space (such spaces are usually called [Polish spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space)). In fact, it is universal in the the following sense: every other Polish space is a quotient space of $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$. This, together with the fact that one can encode a basis of open sets handily using paths in the tree $\omega^{\lt\omega}$ makes the space $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ an extremely important tool in [descriptive set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory). A very nice book on all I'm claiming here and very much more is Kechris's *[Classical descriptive set theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=pPv9KCEkklsC)*, which I heartily recommend.

Comment: There is also Moschovakis' book about descriptive set theory, which is highly recommended by many people as well.

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, true. Moschovakis is a very fine book, too; but I never really worked with it, so I can't recommend it with clear conscience. I find Kechris very interesting because of all its interesting applications to other parts of mathematics.

Comment: Just bringing it up, I have the both open (I have an exam on the subject in a few days) and my teacher praised Moschovakis' book often (although he worked with both, and on some portion he came up with his own proofs and ideas).

Comment: @Asaf: Well, actually I think [Moschovakis](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/) is a person, not a book, but you got my meaning in my previous comment :) Good luck at your exam! (I'm glad that I have all my exams way behind me). As a person working a lot with functional analysis, Kechris is especially appealing because it contains many things that are extremely hard to locate elsewhere (in a language I can understand without much effort, that is).

Comment: @Theo Buehler: thanks a lot!