# In what kind of Polish spaces is there a subset without the Baire property?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Assuming the axiom of choice, we can prove that there are subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ (e.g., the Bernstein sets) that does not have the Baire property. What about a random ($\leftarrow$the everyday meaning is used here, i.e., not a mathematical term) Polish space?

If a Polish space is a countable space with the discrete topology, then there's obviously no such a subset.

If a Polish space is uncountable, then using the Cantor–Bendixson theorem, we can apply the canonical method in the case of $\Bbb{R}$ to the uncountable part got from the deconstruction, which is also a Polish space, and there exists such a subset.

The kind of Polish spaces where there is a subset without the Baire property must be **uncountable** or **countable but with a topology other than the discrete one**. What should the topology be like?

Comment: What goes wrong if you try to run the usual transfinite recursion construction of a Bernstein set in an arbitrary uncountable Polish space?

Comment: Relevant: google search for ["totally imperfect space" + "Baire property"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22totally+imperfect%22+%22Baire+property%22&filter=0) AND google search for ["totally imperfect space" + "Polish space"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22totally+imperfect%22+%22Polish+space%22&filter=0) AND [*Classical theory of totally imperfect spaces*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Classical+theory+of+totally+imperfect+spaces%22&filter=0) by Brown/Cox (1981-1982) AND the MSE question [Totally Imperfect vs Dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50850/13130).